# mongo shell - go to matching bracket / curly braces

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Are there any shortcuts to go to the matching bracket / curly braces in the mongo shell ?
I look into the documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#keyboard-shortcuts) and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of current version of MongoDB (v4.0) there is no built-in shortcuts to go to a matching brackets on `mongo` shell.

You could try to construct the commands through an editor (i.e. vim, etc), or utilise MongoDB GUI (i.e. [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass))